# How to store data in MongoDB that needs to be accessed from both ends (bidirectional)

Tags: mongodb

I have a bunch of players and teams.  Teams are made up of lots of players.  Players can belong to more than one team.  I need to find which players are on a given team or which teams a given player is on.

Would it be best to use DBRefs, a player collection with embedded teams, a team collection with embedded players, both collections, something else, or is MongoDB just not a good choice at all here?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you've read [this page](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design) as well as multiple other discussions of schema design in MongoDB - it can be very helpful to see similar examples and what other people are taking into account.

Having said that, it doesn't sound like your data set is going to be very large - is it?  If that's the case it probably doesn't matter hugely for performance and you should probably strive to design first for clarity and ease of access from your application.

I would think that it's reasonable to have a collection of teams and a collection of players and then decide if you want to have an array of players embedded in each team representing who is on that team, or an array of teams embedded into each player document indicating which teams they are on.  The array could be an array of IDs or IDs and names, etc.

Whichever of the above you pick, querying is easy - if you have team arrays embedded in players, to find out all the players on a particular team you can just query for all players who have that team in their array.   The query might look something like:

db.players.find({"teams.name":"TeamRocky"})

This will return all the player documents for players who have that team name in their "teams" array (this is just an example, your actual implementation may be quite different).  It would be just as easy if you embedded player array in each team document instead.

Things to consider when deciding this should probably include not just how you will be querying the data but also how and how often you expect to be updating the data - will players be moving from team to team?  Will teams dissolve and if so, will you have to track their historical information, etc.

I would encourage you to try some schema and build a small prototype then see what seems problematic and change/evolve the schema as you get more familiar with your application requirements.